# How to fire an event after setting local roles

Tags: python, plone, zope

I'd like to attach the firing of an event with the "manage_setLocalRoles" method.
Like  this:

```
def send_participation_request(self): 
    review_state = self.portal_workflow.getInfoFor(self.context, "review_state", "") 
    if review_state =="public":
        self.context.manage_setLocalRoles(user.id,["Role"]) #fire event
        self.context.reindexObjectSecurity()
    return False
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.manage_setLocalRoles()` does not emit any events. The code predates Zope 3 events.

You'd have to create a monkey-patch hook instead, or otherwise emit an event yourself whenever your own code calls that method.

Comment: @jtmolon: `.reindexObject()` does not emit an event either. There are, however, workflow events when transitions occur, perhaps that is what you are looking for instead?

Comment: Actually I'm just changing the role of a member in a content, there's no workflow transition in the process. What I need to do is update a list after changing the role.